# Issue with Nginx Ingress on kubernetes on AWS EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have been running services on EKS for quite sometime and today accidentally deleted the nginx ingress. Now when i try to setup the ingress using the ingress controller template from the below url with slight modifications:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.34.1/deploy/static/provider/aws/deploy-tls-termination.yaml

It is now not starting the pods. Following issues when viewing the logs appears.

```
kubectl logs -f ingress-nginx-admission-patch-5gvlr -n ingress-nginx


{"level":"info","msg":"patching webhook configurations 'ingress-nginx-admission' mutating=false, validating=true, failurePolicy=Fail","source":"k8s/k8s.go:38","time":"2020-08-23T12:18:32Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Patched hook(s)","source":"k8s/k8s.go:91","time":"2020-08-23T12:18:32Z"}


kubectl logs -f ingress-nginx-admission-create-mj7cd -n ingress-nginx


{"err":"secrets \"ingress-nginx-admission\" not found","level":"info","msg":"no secret found","source":"k8s/k8s.go:101","time":"2020-08-23T12:18:32Z"}
{"level":"info","msg":"creating new secret","source":"cmd/create.go:23","time":"2020-08-23T12:18:32Z"}
```

also attached herewith the iamge of the nginx ingress pods:
[image]

**kubernetes version is 1.17**

can anyone please guide me to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: The error says `ingress-nginx-admission secret is not found`.Check if the secret is there or not

Comment: The error said "msg":"no secret found" but after "msg":"creating new secret". The nginx-controller pod is running fine, the other pod is intend to have this behaviour. Are have some issue to create ingress ??

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have pointed out, when you deleted the ingress, it also deleted the secrets config. You just need to reapply a new one

```
#nginx-secrets.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: default-server-secret
  namespace: ingress-nginx
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: <enter your cert string here>
  tls.key: <enter your cert string here>
```

They keys are allowed to be self-signed, if needed. In the cert strings, DON'T include any lines that look like these;

-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Apply the secrets config BEFORE you apply the ConfigMap. If you've all ready applied the ConfigMap, you'll need to tear it down and start over.

kubectl apply -f nginx-secrets.yaml

kubectl apply -f nginx-config.yaml